# Teradata 15: parsing a string

Tags: sql, parsing, teradata

The task is to scan a string varchar value, which can be null or 3 to N symbols length, and find out if it contains a specific combination in it.

Example:
Find if string `A001G002F001H003Z701` contains `F001` or `B004` or `J005`

Which solution for this task is the most efficient? thx

Comment: update your question ad  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Such query will never be very efficient.

Comment: jarlh yes, and that is why i asked ..

Comment: Dnoeth's answer below is certainly a good answer.  But if this is something you are going to be doing repeatedly, I would look into splitting your string and storing it that way. Doing it once is a lot cheaper than doing it over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `LIKE ANY`:

```
WHERE x LIKE ANY ( '%F001%', '%B004%', '%J005%')
```

or a RegEx:

```
WHERE RegExp_Instr(x, 'F001|B004|J005') > 0
```

Run it against a huge table and compare CPU using Query Log